# update table with multi checkbox in php

Tags: php

I have multi check box with in the form and when click the submit button the table in database updated and when the check box is checked this code is correct but when the check box is not checked the table was not updated!

```
<form method="post">
<?php
$qr2=$mysqli->query("SELECT `action_id`,`enable` FROM `role`");
    for($i=0;$row2=$qr2->fetch_object();$i++){
?>
    <input type="checkbox" <?php if($row2->enable == '1'){ ?> checked <?php } ?> id="upc" name="upc[]" value="<?php echo $row2->action_id; ?>">
<?php
    }
?>
<input type="submit" id="up" name="up" value="update">
<?php update_role(); ?>
</form>

<?php
function update_role(){
    if(isset($_POST['up'])){
        foreach($_POST['upc'] as $check) {
            if(isset($_POST['upc'])) {
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE `role` SET `enable`='1' WHERE `action_id`='$check'");
            }
            else{
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE `role` SET `enable`='0' WHERE `action_id`='$check'");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Edit:

A textbox is used near the check box and show "price" for this role and i want to update table for this value:

```
<form method="post">
    <?php
    $qr2=$mysqli->query("SELECT `action_id`,`enable`,`price`,`id` FROM `role`");
        for($i=0;$row2=$qr2->fetch_object();$i++){
    ?>
        <input type="checkbox" <?php if($row2->enable == '1'){ ?> checked <?php } ?> id="upc" name="upc[]" value="<?php echo $row2->action_id; ?>">
        <input type="text" class="nw-prc" value="<?php echo $row2->price; ?>" name="price[<?php echo $row2->id; ?>]">
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" id="up" name="up" value="update">
    <?php update_role(); ?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment I think you want to update the database with all the values from the selected boxes, even if they are not selected (deselected by the user)

I've updated my answer with an example. You can do this in many ways, this is just an example of how you could do that.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <?php
            // Configure your database connection
            $servername = "";
            $username = "";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "";
            $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
            }

            $role = update_role();

            foreach ($role as $actionId => $enable) {
                echo sprintf(
                    '<input type="checkbox" %s id="upc" name="upc[]" value="%s">',
                    $enable == '1' ? 'checked="checked"' : "",
                    $actionId
                );
            }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" id="up" name="up" value="update">
        </form>

<?php
/**
 * Return an array which contains the configured role settings.
 * In the format array($actionId => $enable)
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *  array(
 *      1 => '0',
 *      422 => '1'
 *  );
 *
 * @return array
 */
function update_role()
{
    global $mysqli;

    $qr2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT `action_id`,`enable` FROM `role`");
    $role = [];

    // Put the role from the database in an array.
    for ($i=0; $row2=$qr2->fetch_object(); $i++) {
        $role[$row2->action_id] = $row2->enable;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['up'])) {
        $isUpcSelected = isset($_POST['upc']) ? true : false;

        // Loop the role array and make the default 'enable' value '0' because on the server you will only receive
        // which checkboxes are selected in the $_POST array. This means that $isUpcSelected can be false on a POST.
        // But we also want to update the select boxes that are not selected/deselected, which they are now by default.
        foreach ($role as $actionId => $enable) {
            $role[$actionId] = '0';
        }

        // Now if there are selected checkboxes, then get them from the $_POST array and set their value to '1'.
        if ($isUpcSelected) {
            foreach ($_POST['upc'] as $checked) {
                if (array_key_exists($checked, $role)) {
                    $role[$checked] = '1';
                }
            }
        }

        // Then update the database with the values from the $role array.
        foreach ($role as $actionId => $enable) {
            $mysqli->query("UPDATE `role` SET `enable`='$enable' WHERE `action_id`='$actionId'");
        }
    }

    return $role;
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tnx!what is the solution for getting value multi checkbox is not checked??

Comment: @FatemehNamkhah
If I understand your question correctly, you want to know if the multi selectbox was checked and create a variable for that?

In that case you can check the $_POST array for ['upc'] and create a boolean variable for that:

$isUpcSelected = isset($_POST['upc']) ? true : false;

Comment: No.I want to be save this to database:

Comment: checkbox is checked -> enable     &&   checkbox is not checked ->disable